# Check php soap and xml rpc extensions are enabled or not

Tags: php, xml, magento

i am facing this error :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32367682/magento-soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-failed-to-load-external-ent

i want to check php soap and xml rpc extensions are enabled or not in the following link :

https://videomergerapp.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1

please hep me to find solution

thanks in advance

Comment: Try to get **phpinfo** of server. If you have ssh connection with server run `php -m` it will list enabled extension

Comment: is it enabled in our site : http://videomergerapp.com/clone.php

Comment: It seems its not enabled.  try to add php with following script. it will show clearly all your enabled extensions. `<?php
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>`

Comment: please check now : http://videomergerapp.com/clone.php

Comment: delete that file from server. Its not good to public phpinfo.

Comment: please help me how i can enable that ?

Comment: Soap is enabled but xmlrpc not enabled

Comment: You need to edit your php.ini  from server

Comment: i found this url to edit php.ini file

http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/server-usage/edit-main-phpini

can you please inform what i need to be change in php.ini file for

to enable "php soap and xml rpc extensions"

Comment: You can contact support team too. since its server information you should keep it secret.

Comment: okay, i will inform about the status later....

Comment: please post your comment as answer....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get active extension list using below methods.

1) create a php script with `phpinfo();` script and upload to your server, it will display all php setting information on your server.

2) if you have command line ( ssh ) connection with your server use `php -m` command to know active list of extension.

3) Create a page with below script, it will list all active extension.

`<?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); ?>`

In order to enable/disable extension, changes in **php.ini** is required, many hosting provider provide alternate ways to change this ini file. In order to do required changes you can also contact to your server support team.